# Mapping coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.4

I have a set of data of decimal coordinates along a route, that are spaced unevenly, here is a sample -

```
Lat, Long
53.307718   -6.230189
53.307708   -6.229988
53.307759   -6.229844
53.3078     -6.229689
53.307804   -6.229518
53.307794   -6.229342
53.307805   -6.22919
53.307816   -6.229026
53.307807   -6.228855
53.307806   -6.228703
53.307788   -6.228534
53.307796   -6.228356
53.307784   -6.228166
53.307771   -6.227999
53.307768   -6.227839
53.30775    -6.227648
53.307743   -6.227467
53.307741   -6.227285
53.307725   -6.227111
53.307713   -6.226935
53.307688   -6.226761
```

I was wondering is it possible to use GIS to input these points and then measure the distance between the points and then output the coordinate every nth meter.

Answer (score 1):

Put the coordinates in a CSV, add the CSV to ArcMap, right-click on the file in Table of Contents, choose "Display XY Data", specify X as "Long" and Y as "Lat" and coordinate system as WGS 1984 in the dialog, click "OK" and you will see the points.

Comment: yes i know how to add the data to ArcMap, but once i do that can i then measure the distances connecting each point, and then get the coordinates every 5 meters along the route made by the original points

Answer (score 1):

Linear Referencing. Turn your line into a route (m aware) feature. If it is just a distance along a single line it is fairly trivial. Check that the line has no geometry issues (make a copy > start editing, select all, merge, explode, check table for single record only. Double click on the line and look to see if the end vertex (red one) is at an end of the line).

Just run "Create Route" from the Linear Referencing toolbox. Specify the "Coordinate Priority" to indicate where you would like the 0 length to be (start of line). After you have a route you can theme it with hatching or edit vertices and double check the "M" distance values are the correct direction if you want. Anyways... you should now have a route. Now run "Locate Features Along Routes" with your points and the routed line and you should get a table of the distances along that line that the points occur at.

You might need to define projections and ensure the datasets are both the same since you are inputting a lat/long dataset. I doubt an answer in arc seconds is of much use to you :)

Outputting coordinates at set distances is even easier. Just create an empty point dataset. Start editing, make the points the target, select the line and from the edit toolbar select "Construct Points".

Comment: im finding it hard to follow and apply what your saying